# Fragments as ListView rows (Google Maps Android API v2)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-listview, android-fragments

In the past, it was impossible to have more than one MapView displayed in an Activity, in part because we had to use MapActivity to manage the view. However, with the recent release of [Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/),  displaying multiple maps is trivial.

In the new API there are 2 ways of displaying the widget: using a `MapView` or using a `MapFragment`. Using the fragment is considered easier since the view requires that the developer forwards all of the life-cycle methods.

My application calls for static maps to be displayed as the rows of a `ListView`. I was originally going to implements this using the [Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) and handle the networking myself. However it seems that using the new maps API would be much more productive.

This brings me to my main question. Is it possible/advised to use fragments inside `ListView` rows? The only similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363309/can-a-listview-contain-fragments) I found didn't really get anywhere but I would imagine that this is possible now that we can nest fragments.

Answer (score 0):

> My application calls for static maps to be displayed as the rows of a ListView

That is unlikely to work, as the list probably will not be scrollable, at least without the user panning the map to one of the poles.

> Is it possible/advised to use fragments inside ListView rows?

It may be impossible. I certainly would not advise it. `ViewPager` specifically eschews `ListAdapter` for its own `PagerAdapter` specifically to make using fragments in pages be more practical.

Comment: "That is unlikely to work, as the list probably will not be scrollable, at least without the user panning the map to one of the poles." - I don't need the maps to be scrollable so I will just turn that capability off. Afterall, I was going to use images for these.

I guess I knew it wasn't a good idea. I was just hopeful. Back to forwarding life-cycle events then.

Comment: What did you use at the end??? I have a similar idea, but didn't know if it is a good to pursue...