# Add fragment into listview item

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I want to have a fragment for each item in a listview, because I want to separate some logic out. I am using a view holder for each item. If the view doesn't exist, I create a new fragment and add it into the container.

```
holder.mMyFragment = new MyFragment(mActivity, this);
mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.my_container, holder.mMyFragment).commit();
```

Also for each item, I call holder.mMyFragment.setUi(dataSource, position) to set UI of the fragment based on the data source and position.

The problem I'm having is I initialize the UI elements of fragment in onCreateView method of the fragment class, but it's not called when I add the fragment to the item. So later when I call setUi() which uses some UI elements in fragment it complains a NullPointerException. Does anyone have a suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: It's late but @Brabbeldas ask me about how I got it, so I updated my answer. I'm using it in a private app.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I want to have a fragment for each item in a listview, because I want to separate some logic out.

You can't use fragment as list item views because the API doesn't allow you - `View` and `Fragment` aren't even related so there's no way you can use it like that. Make custom views and use adapter `getViewTypeCount` and `getView` to use different list item behavior.

Fragment are managed by Activity's FragmentManager or by other Fragments child FragmentManager; while list item views are managed by ListView & ListAdapter. You can use ListViews in Fragments, but not the other way around.

Comment: No. **WE CAN USE Fragments as a list item** . Please find my answer below and Vote :)

Comment: API allows to add Fragment in a View. 
So If listView has list of Views, it can have list of Fragments too.

Answer (score 13):

"**THERE IS A SOLUTION**" for this.

The issue is, you ***cannot add fragment directly to the container***(FrameLayout) with same "id" in listview as you have done in the above code.

The **trick** is, create listview(Recyclerview) of "LinearLayout". Then *dynamically* create FrameLayout in adapter and assign ***different id's*** for each. Inflate Fragment to FrameLayout and this FrameLayout to LinearLayout.

```
@Override
protected void onBindBasicItemView(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder instanceof VideoHomeViewHolder) {
        VideoHomeViewHolder videoHomeViewHolder = (VideoHomeViewHolder) holder;
        FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(mContext);
        frameLayout.setId(position+1); //since id cannot be zero
        FragmentHelper.popBackStackAndReplace(mFragmentManager, frameLayout.getId(),
                new ShowLatestVideosFragment(mShowLatestVideosItems.get(position)));
        videoHomeViewHolder.linearLayout.addView(frameLayout);
    }
}
```

Comment: you solution is working but there is an exception sometimes     No view found for id 0x2 for fragment

Comment: in my case i am data list is updated and there is no constant time for as it reflects the changes from server , like item might be added or removed so i have to update adapter accordingly i am suing notify item inserted , notifyitemremoved and notifyrangeupdated as well

Comment: what inside the FragmentHelper.popBackStackAndReplace() function?

Answer (score 3):

A simple way.
One problem:You should store add restore fragment state.

```
holder.mMyFragment = new MyFragment(mActivity, this);
int id = View.generateViewId();
findViewByTag("abc").setId(id);
mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(id, holder.mMyFragment).commit();
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi I was facing the same problem and I found the way to do it.
My problem was similar to you:

> "I want to have a fragment for each item in a listview, because I want to separate some logic out"

In my app I have to give the option to display custom items in vertical (listView) and horizontal (ViewPager) mode. Additionally I had to deal with 18 custom items and each one with different logic, so the best approach was reusing the fragments that I was using for ViewPager in ListView.

I got it but not in the way you were trying, I mean, I used my fragments like "ViewHolders":

1. Define fragment's widget like variables of class in each fragment.
2. Create a custom ArrayAdapter and override: `getViewTypeCount(), getItemViewType(int position), getCount(), getItem(int position) getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`

In `getView` I checked what kind of layout I needed before "inflate" the respective XML, create a fragment, assign widget from XML to fragment (with `rootView.findViewById`) and set "tag" with the new fragment.
What you can see at this point is that fragments in ListView never got attached to Activity but you got what you wanted: logic distributed in several parts and all benefits of ListView (reuse of rows, scroll, etc).
If you need I can post part of my code but you have to deal with "spanglish" ;).

**UPDATED**

All the problem is because when you create a Fragment to be used with ViewPager, usually all "layout and "setup" code is inside `onCreateView` method, I mean:

- Get the view object you are going to use (`View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question_horizontal_container, container, false);`)
- Get the widgets from above layout, define behaviors, fonts, etc: (`answer = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.answer_question_text);`)

Until this point there is nothing weird.
If you are going to use a fragment with the behavior described above you have to "emulate" the call to onCreateView, fill the data and attach it to the listView.
**Here is the trick:** split the code in `onCreateView` in some methods that doesn't care about who's calling them. An example of my `onCreateView`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pregunta_horizontal_container, container, false);

    addAnswerLayout(rootView, R.layout.fragment_pregunta_texto, getActivity());
    setUpComponents(rootView);
    //those 2 methods are about my app logic so I'm not going to talk much about them
    setUpQuestionState(savedInstanceState);
    readSavedAnswer();

    return rootView;
}

public void addAnswerLayout(View rootView, int optionId, Context context) {

    mContext = context;

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.pregunta_container);

    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)mContext).getLayoutInflater();
    View newView = inflater.inflate(optionId, relativeLayout, false);

    relativeLayout.addView(newView);
}

public void setUpComponents(View rootView) {
    //next line: some heritage that you can ignore
    super.setUpComponents(rootView);

    respuesta = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.pregunta_respuesta_texto);
    respuesta.setTypeface(UiHelper.getInstance(getActivity()).typeface);
    respuesta.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.drs_gris));

    ...
}
```

Now let's go to the CustomArrayAdapter for list view:

- Define your customArrayAdapter something like this: `PreguntasVerticalArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Pregunta>` where "Pregunta" is a generic Fragment with the logic from above.
- Override `getViewTypeCount(), getItemViewType(int position), getCount(), getItem(int position) getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`.

The `getView` follow the same behavior: get the object for the given position in params, reuse a "viewholder" and fill the data. Here my `getView`:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View rowView = convertView;

    Pregunta pregunta = mData.get(position);

    if (rowView == null)
        rowView = createQuestionUI(pregunta, parent, position);

    fillDataInRow((PreguntaUI)rowView.getTag(), pregunta, position);

    return rowView;
}

private View createPreguntaUI(Pregunta pregunta, ViewGroup parent, int position) {

    View rootView = null;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (mPreguntasVerticalFragment.getActivity()).getLayoutInflater();

    //you can ignore this part of the code ralted to Bundle.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putLong(PreguntaUI.PREGUNTAUI_ID, pregunta.getIdpregunta());
    args.putInt(PreguntaUI.PREGUNTAUI_INDEX, position);
    args.putInt(PreguntaUI.PREGUNTAUI_TOTAL_QUESTIONS, getCount());

    //internal method of "pregunta" to know what kind of question it is.
    String tipo = pregunta.getTipo();

    if (tipo.equalsIgnoreCase(PreguntaType.TEXT.toString())) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pregunta_vertical_container, parent, false);

        Pregunta_texto pregunta_texto = new Pregunta_texto();
        pregunta_texto.setArguments(args);

        //LOOK AT THIS POINT!!!: I'm calling the same methods that I called in onCreateView fragment's method.
        pregunta_texto.addAnswerLayout(rootView, R.layout.fragment_pregunta_texto,
                mPreguntasVerticalFragment.getActivity());
        pregunta_texto.setUpComponents(rootView);
        pregunta_texto.setUpQuestionState(null);
        pregunta_texto.readSavedAnswer();

        //I'm adding the fragment to reuse it when I can
        rootView.setTag(pregunta_texto);
    }
    else if ...

    return rootView;
}
```

That is all... at this point, if you have enough experience dealing with CustomArrayAdapters and Fragments you probably got it! :D

Comment: Hi 0mahc0, yes please, could you post some of your logic?

Comment: Sure, give me somedays (weekend)

Comment: I am curious how you got it working because lots of people say it is not possible to add fragments into a ListView, e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363309/can-a-listview-contain-fragments

Comment: @Brabbeldas Ready. I updated my answer. Hope it can help you and others.

Answer (score -1):

From the Android Documentation : "A **Fragment** represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity. You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities."

For your activity, do you want to add 2 fragments where the first one displays a listView (**= ListFragment** and the other one is in the right and is shown only when the user clicks on an item (from the first fragment or listView) ?

Answer (score -3):

Instead of using ListFragment, you can use RecyclerView, Android has documentation on that:

[image]

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html#AddInLayout