# Fragment Inside raw layout of recycler view

Tags: android

Can I have a fragment inside the row layout of a recycler view and inflate it on touch of an item inside the row layout itself?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting thing.

> Well you can not !!

For reason please go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645316/add-fragment-into-listview-item/18645419#18645419)