# I am using fragments in my project but when i click on a button it restart application

Tags: android, android-studio, fragment

Here is code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

          mview=  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_noification, container, false);
    SOP=Shared.getInstance().getsop(getActivity());

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) mview.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    data_list = new ArrayList<>();
    arsa= mview.findViewById( R.id.ars);


    //       mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) mview.findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);
// mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener((SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener) mview);


    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

    adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), (ArrayList<MyData>) data_list);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    img = (ImageView) mview.findViewById(R.id.noinfo);
    txt1 = (TextView) mview.findViewById(R.id.networkerror);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) mview.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    cm = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);


    activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    arsa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(context,"Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you share error log?

Comment: Please share your error log and take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn´t use fragments in a RecyclerView, it isn´t support Fragments, for more information you can read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645316/add-fragment-into-listview-item/18645419#18645419)

Answer (score 0):

It's due to your `context` null

Change this

```
 Toast.makeText(context,"Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

To

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```