# Fragment only attach in 1st Holder, not In All Holder RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

i would like to ask, why is my holder only showing the 1st FragmentContainerView(fragment child) in recyclerview, but the 2nd and rest not showing.

Is there any code that i'm missing out? or should I do other approach?

This is MyAdapter.

```
 class CertificateAdapter constructor(
        fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
        val onClick: (Certificate) -> Unit
    ) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<CertificateAdapter.ItemHolder>() {

        private var listCertificate = arrayListOf<Certificate>()

        private var mManager = fragmentManager

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(
            parent: ViewGroup,
            viewType: Int
        ): CertificateAdapter.ItemHolder {
            return ItemHolder(
                V3ViewSubCertificateBinding.inflate(
                    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                    parent,
                    false
                )
            )
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemHolder, position: Int) =
            holder.bind(listCertificate[position])

        override fun getItemCount() = listCertificate.size

        inner class ItemHolder(
            private val binding: V3ViewSubCertificateBinding,
        ) :
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root),
            TextViewBindingAdapter.AfterTextChanged,
            UploadPhotoListener {
            private var cert = Certificate()

            fun bind(certificate: Certificate) {
                val mFragmentManager = mManager
                cert = certificate

                with(binding) {
                    holder = this@ItemHolder
                    imageClose.setOnSafeClickListener {
                        deleteItem(certificate)
                    }
                    itemNumber = (bindingAdapterPosition + 1).toString()

                    (mFragmentManager
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.fg_upload_certificate) as? 
NewUploadFragment)?.apply {
                        setTitle(getString(R.string.upload_info_training_certification))
                        setImageViewType(ImageType.TRAINING_CERTIFICATE)
                        setUploadPhotoListener(this@ItemHolder)
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                when (s.hashCode()) {
                    binding.formTrainingName.inputLayout.code() -> {
                        //handle ET1 text change
                    }
                    binding.formYear.inputLayout.code() -> {
                        //handle ET2 text change
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun setUploadPhotoResult(imageViewType: ImageType?, imageUrl: String?) {
                //handle photo upload result
            }
        }

        fun addItem(certificate: Certificate) {
            listCertificate.add(certificate)
            notifyItemInserted(this.listCertificate.size)
        }

        fun deleteItem(certificate: Certificate) {
            listCertificate.remove(certificate)
            notifyItemRemoved(this.listCertificate.size)
            if (listCertificate.size == Constant.ZERO) {
                clearItem()
            }
        }

        fun clearItem() {
            listCertificate = arrayListOf()
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
```

My ItemXML, to use in holder Recyclerview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="certificate"
            type="Certificate" />

        <variable
            name="itemNumber"
            type="String" />

        <variable
            name="holder"
            type="CertificateAdapter.ItemHolder" />
    </data>

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        style="@style/CardView.0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout style="@style/Layout.Vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText 1/>

            <EditText 2/>

            <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
                android:id="@+id/fg_upload_certificate"
                android:name="v2.upload.NewUploadFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_16dp"
                android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/_16dp"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_new_upload_photo" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
</layout>
```

My ParentFragment
from parent i have access to delete and Add Item to my adapter.

```
class AmbassadorExperienceFragment : BaseFragment {
    private val mBinding by bindingDelegates {
        V3FragmentAmbassadorExperienceBinding.bind(
            requireView()
        )
    }

    private val mAdapter: CertificateAdapter by lazy {
        CertificateAdapter(
            onClick =
            { certificate ->
                mAdapter.deleteItem(certificate)
            },
            fragmentManager = this@AmbassadorExperienceFragment.childFragmentManager
        )
    }

    override fun getLayout() = R.layout.v3_fragment_ambassador_experience

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      
    }
    
        private val onClickProcess: (View) -> Unit = { view ->
            when (view) {
                mBinding.buttonAddCertification -> {
                    mAdapter.addItem(Certificate())
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: IMAGE 1 HAS FRAGMENT UPLOAD]

[image: IMAGE 2 NO FRAGMENT UPLOAD]

Answer (score 0):

was searching for the same thing today and found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645316/add-fragment-into-listview-item/18645419#18645419)

So from what I understood reading the answer is that you shouldn't do it and instead use multiple Viewholders.