# IllegalArgumentException instantiating SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-maps-v2, android-cursoradapter, illegalargumentexception

I'm working with a DB in which are logged for each entry, along with other infos, latitude and longitude too.

Developing the "consumption part" of the app, in which a list of the entries is generated and showed via a `CursorAdapter`, I'm stuck on a annoying error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #85: Duplicate id 0x7f050070, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment

I googled and found that it's due to a multiple instantiation of the same fragment. But since it's not a simple Fragment, but something attached dinamically every time `bindView()` is called, I don't actually know how to delete all nested fragments...

**ReadActivity** calls *CursorAdapterSpese*

```
    Cursor c = mDb.rawGet("SELECT * FROM "+MySQLiteHelper.SPESE_NAME);      

    if (c.getCount() == 0) {
        mLlNonTrovato.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);      
    } else {
        CursorAdapterSpese dataAdapter = new CursorAdapterSpese(this, c, R.layout.item_movimento);
        mLista.setAdapter(dataAdapter);         
    }

    mDb.close();
```

While in **CursorAdapterSpese** the most important method is:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {

    // [...]

    GoogleMap map = 
            ((SupportMapFragment) (((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.READ_map)))
            .getMap();

    final double lat = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MySQLiteHelper.SPESE_KEY_LAT));
    final double lon = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MySQLiteHelper.SPESE_KEY_LON));


    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lon)).title(tipo));

}
```

Finally, **READ_map** is very simply:

```
   <fragment
        android:id="@+id/READ_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite clear on your setup, so correct me if I'm wrong.  You're using a cursor adapter, which implies you have a listview with a map in each cell, and you want to put a single marker on each map, populated by the database.  If that's the case, I think you are getting the wrong fragment.  `((SupportMapFragment) (((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.READ_map))).getMap();` looks for the fragment in your fragment activity, in this case I think it's your ReadActivity.  What you want is to look for the fragment in the relevant cell in your listview.

However, I'm not sure that that's possible.  Also, it's not a good idea to put fragments inside a listview, check out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363309/can-a-listview-contain-fragments).  I'd recommend finding a different way to display your information, that pulls the map data out of the listview into a single map.