# add fragment to recycler view item

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

Taking reference from these

[Can a ListView contain Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363309/can-a-listview-contain-fragments)

[Add fragment into listview item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645316/add-fragment-into-listview-item)

I'm trying to create Recycler view item using following code:

```
 SingleImageViewFragment fragment = new SingleImageViewFragment();
 FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout(getActivity(context));
 int id = View.generateViewId();
 layout.setId(id);
 getActivity(context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(layout.getId(), fragment)
.commit();// **this line causing problem**
return layout;
```

- Above code is used to initialise recycler view holder.

but getting following Error :

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find
>   resource ID #0x1
>                                                                                          at android.content.res.Resources.getResourceName(Resources.java:3014)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1059)

I'm using recycler view with LinearLayoutManager.

Comment: can u post code of generateViewId()

Comment: sorry typo mistake, It must be View.generateViewId();

Comment: typo mistake here or in your code?

Comment: It looks your SingleImageViewFragment has issues

Comment: what can be  the issue? It is the class that extends fragment.

Comment: Some view you are referring does not exist there

Comment: from error message and my searching till now, layout.getId() is some how not present in getActivity(context) context/tree. but how then it is present in the case of listview? I'm not able to find the issueor any reasoning

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123177/discussion-between-sandeep-sharma-and-nayan-srivastava).

Comment: @SandeepSharma did you find a solution, fragments can be added, but notifydatasetchange is causing issue, like swipe refresh